# $\sin 2a + \sin 2b + \sin 2c - \sin 2(a+b+c) = 4 \sin (a+b) \sin (b+c) \sin (c+a)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am clueless about this homework question. Looking at it, I see I could use the compound angle and and sum formulas, and tried using them. Unfortunately, couldn't proceed beyond that. Help?

$$\sin 2a + \sin 2b + \sin 2c - \sin 2(a+b+c) = 4 \sin (a+b) \sin (b+c) \sin (c+a)$$

Comment: Have you tried $ \sin( y + x ) = \cos ( x ) \sin (y) + \cos ( y ) \sin ( x) $ ? What have you achieved?

Comment: @PenasRaul I did, but that resulted in too long an expression.

Comment: But you would arrive to two polynomials on $\sin ( a )$ and $\cos (a)$  which would certainly have the same coefficients (assuming the equality is right) modulo the equation $sin^2 + cos^2 = 1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\sin2A+\sin2B=2\sin(A+B)\cos(A-B)$$

and $$\sin(2A+2B+2C)-\sin2C=2\sin(A+B)\cos(A+B+2C)$$

Finally,
$$\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B+2C)=2\sin(A+C)\sin(B+C)$$

Comment: This is a beautiful solution

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @labbhattacharjee. Here's a step by step version of their solution:

$$\sin 2a + \sin 2b + \sin 2c - \sin 2(a+b+c) = 4 \sin (a+b) \sin (b+c) \sin (c+a)$$

LHS:

$ = 2 \sin (a+b) \cos (a-b) + \sin 2c - \sin((2a+2b)+2c) $
$ = 2 \sin (a+b) \cos (a-b) + 2 \cos (a+b+2c) \sin (-a-b) $
$ = 2 \sin (a+b) \cos (a-b) + 2 \cos (a+b+2c) \sin (-a-b) $ 
$ = 2 \sin (a+b) \cos (a-b) - 2 \cos (a+b+2c) \sin (a+b) $
$ = 2 \sin (a+b) (\cos (a-b) - \cos (a+b+2c)) $
$ = 2 \sin (a+b) (-2 \sin (c+a) \sin (-b-c)) $
$ = 2 \sin (a+b) (2 \sin (c+a) \sin (b+c)) $
$ = 4 \sin (a+b) \sin (b+c) \sin (c+a) $